# calculate vector valued Hessian in R

Tags: r, optimization, covariance, variance, minimization

I want to calculate a variance-covariance matrix of parameters. The parameters are obtained by a non-linear least squares fit.

```
library(minpack.lm)
library(numDeriv)
```

#### variables

```
t <- seq(0.1,20,0.3)
a <- 20
b <- 14
c <- 0.4
jitter <- rnorm(length(t),0,0.5)
Hobs <- a+b*exp(-c*t)+jitter
```

#### function def

```
Hhat <- function(parList, t) {parList$a + parList$b*exp(-parL
Hhatde <- function(par, t) {par[1] + par[2]*exp(-par[3]*t)}st$c*t)}
residFun <- function(par, t, observed) observed - Hhat(par,t)
```

#### initial conditions

```
parStart = list(a = 20, b = 10 ,c = 0.5)
```

#### nls.lm

```
library(minpack.lm)
out1 <- nls.lm(par = parStart, fn = residFun, observed = Hobs,
              t = t, control = nls.lm.control(nprint=0))
```

I wish to calculate manually what is given back via `vcov(out1)`
I tried it with: but `sigma` and `vcov(out1)` which don't seem to be the same

```
J <- jacobian(Hhatde, c(19.9508523,14.6586555,0.4066367 ), method="Richardson", 
method.args=list(),t=t)
sigma <- solve((t(J)%*%J))
vcov(out1)
```

now trying to do it with the hessian, I can't get it working for error message cf below

#### hessian

```
H <- hessian(Hhatde, x = c(19.9508523,14.6586555,0.4066367 ), method="complex", method.args=list(),t=t)

Error in hessian.default(Hhatde, x = c(19.9508523, 14.6586555, 0.4066367),  : 
  Richardson method for hessian assumes a scalar valued function.
```

How do I do I get my `hessian()` to work.

I am not very strong on the math here, hence the trial and error approach.

Comment: If i multiply `sigma` by the standard error squared*, then I get approximately the same values as with `vcov(out1)`.
Is that correct?

* Residual standard error: 0.53 on 64 degrees of freedom from the command `summary(out1)`. I am not quite sure how this is computed.
But is probably is: `var(residuals(out1))^0.5`

Comment: The code you've given for your non-linear function is incomplete (under function def heading). Although it is not necessary for to answer your question, I suggest you correct it for the sake of a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

`vcov(out1)` returns an estimate of the scaled variance-covariance matrix for the parameters in your model. The inverse of the cross product of the gradient, `solve(crossprod(J))` returns an estimate of the unscaled variance-covariance matrix. The scaling factor is the estimated variance of the errors. So to calculate the scaled variance-covariance matrix (with some rounding error) using the gradient and the residuals from your model:

```
df = length(Hobs) - length(out1$par)                # degrees freedom
se_var = sum(out1$fvec^2) / df                      # estimated error variance
var_cov = se_var * solve(crossprod(J))              # scaled variance-covariance 

print(var_cov)                                      
print(vcov(out1))
```

To brush up on non-linear regression and non-linear least squares, you might wish to check out Seber & Wild's *Nonlinear regression*, or Bates & Watts' *Nonlinear regression analysis and its applications*. John Fox also has a short [online appendix](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion-1E/appendix-nonlinear-regression.pdf) that you may find helpful.